# .removeClass firing too soon?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, css, webkit, removeclass

I have a bizarre problem. It happens only on Chrome 24 (AFAIK) so it **might be** a Chrome bug but in case if it isn't I want to future proof my script.

I have a library for a [full screen CSS3 gallery](https://github.com/mrfoto/mrsi-gallery). Now my library is huge, overly complicated and it has many fancy features like CSS3 fadeouts if configured so (jQuery by default). Now jQuery transitions works just fine as do (awkwardly) CSS3 transitions. The problem is only with the first image loaded by CSS3 transition.

I've spent the last two hours isolating the problem and I found it. The problem is that `.removeClass('fadeout')` fires too early. I can't completely comprehend why this would happen but the only possible explanation I have is that CSS is not loaded when gallery fires `.removeClass('fadeout')`. It seems completely unreal since browser first loads CSS and then later it starts loading jQuery and after jQuery is ready it loads my gallery library and then when that one is ready, I load the function which initiates the gallery and starts the procedure of loading the first image.

So, not to delay any longer, this is the code, that causes problems:

```
self.backgroundDiv.css(self.transitionClass).on(self.transitionType, stopRunning).removeClass('fadeout')
```

To explain - `self.backgroundDiv` holds the jQuery container for the div which holds the background image. `.css(self.transitionClass)` adds the transitions on that div:

```
{-moz-transition: "1000ms", -o-transition: "1000ms", -webkit-transition: "1000ms", transition: "1000ms"}
```

The `.on(self.transitionType, stopRunning)` binds a browser specific event of transition ending to fire a function that tells the library the first image has loaded.

So now I've looked into all that figuring out if they dropped the browser prefix from the `webkitTransitionEnd` event and literally going line by line through the whole process of adding the first image and it all works fine. So then all I was left with was this fadeout class and when I tried that I couldn't believed that it was it.

How do I know that was the problem? Cause the above didn't work, but this made it work perfectly:

```
window.aaa = self.backgroundDiv.css(self.transitionClass).on(self.transitionType, stopRunning);
setTimeout("window.aaa.removeClass('fadeout')", 0);
```

So my question is - how is it possible that `.removeClass` fires too early and how to fix that (other than ugly setTimeout)? Is there anyway I could check when the CSS is loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: @TarasNeporozhniy I made an [ugly fix](https://github.com/mrfoto/mrsi-gallery/commit/73ccff8e294173b34db06a1b64f1472ffee456d6)